# What is the best way to remove dataset rows with missing values?

Tags: dataset, core-language

Consider a rectangular dataset produced by `SemanticImport` from a CSV file where the first row has the headers. Some values are Missing. I want to delete all the rows with missing values.  I'm using `DeleteCases[dataset, KeyValuePattern[_ -> _Missing]]`, which has been working fine for small datasets.  What is the recommended approach?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @MarcoB 1. It is such a common need, that I suspect I am overlooking a builtin (faster) approach that would be more appropriate for large datasets. 2. In particular, faster builtin functions often supplant pattern-based approaches. (But I did not find one.)

Comment: `DeleteMissing` has a 3rd argument you can use to specify how deep you want to check for Missing values. For example, `DeleteMissing[data, 1, Infinity]` will look through the 1st level of the dataset and delete anything on the 1st level that has Missing at any deeper level.

Comment: I noticed that, but the documentation suggested to me that `DeleteMissing` is not promised to work: "`DeleteMissing` does not enter heads other than `List` or `Association`". But I also see it does work. Is that guaranteed? Does "enter" in this case mean starting at the specified level?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit See last comment. And a further question: the documentation for `DeleteMissing` refers to "levels" of the expression, but a dataset is an atom ...

Comment: But then, the `DeleteCases` documentation also refers to levels ...

Comment: @Alan I think the remarks about entering only lists and associations refers to the 2nd argument and not the 3rd one. As for datasets being atomic: that's just a top-level optimization just like associations being atoms that behave non-atomically.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yet `Level` fails. I think another terminology is needed.

Comment: There's no denying that `Dataset` is a bit of a strange beast. Personally, I think that working with ordinary lists and associations and then operating on them with `Query` is usually easier. I mostly use `Dataset` as an output wrapper for display. But that's another discussion.